# Repeating a loop until the right random value is selected

Tags: python

I am trying to make a program that randomly selects a number, and then you have to guess that number until you get that number correct. So far it works so that I can guess one time, and then the program ends, i need it to repeat my input until i guess the correct number.

```
import random
a = random.randint(1,20)
print("My number is somewhere between one and twenty")
b = int(input("What is your guess?: "))
if b == a:
    print("You guessed my number!")
elif b > a:
    print("You're number is too large")
elif b < a:
    print("You're number is too small")     

input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit")
```

Comment: Use  a `while` loop. See [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WhileLoop).

Comment: Tutorials are your friend: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/python_loops.htm

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the `while` loop which will execute until a certain condition is met. In your case, the code would be like this:

```
import random
a = random.randint(1,20)
print("My number is somewhere between one and twenty")
b = 0  # We create the variable b
while b != a:  # This executes while b is not a
    b = int(input("What is your guess?: "))
    if b > a:
        print("Your number is too large")
    elif b < a:
        print("Your number is too small")     
print("You guessed my number!")  # At this point, we know b is equal to a

input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit")
```

Answer (score 0):

It's working

```
import random
a = random.randint(1,20)
print("My number is somewhere between one and twenty")
while True: #missing the while loop
    b = int(input("What is your guess?: "))
    if b == a:
        print("You guessed my number!")
        exit()
    elif b > a:
        print("You're number is too large")
    elif b < a:
        print("You're number is too small")
```

Comment: Keep in mind that `exit()` not only breaks out of the loop, but also stops the program. Also, according to the docs, it's "useful for the interactive interpreter shell and should not be used in programs". From https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#exit